# Is using multiple gesture listeners bad practice? How to tie them together?

Tags: android, gesture

I need to detect bot Pinch and Double Tapping events on my app. So I created one `ScaleGestureDetector` and one `GestureDetector` and set them both to run on my `onTouchEvent`. It works. Both events are triggered correctly. However is this a bad practice? Should I (Can I?) find a way to put them together in the same `GestureDetector`?

Detectors:

```
private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        Log.d(TAG,"mScaleFactor:" + mScaleFactor);
        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));
        mScaleFactor = mScaleFactor > maxScaleFactor ? maxScaleFactor :
                            mScaleFactor < minScaleFactor ? minScaleFactor :
                                mScaleFactor;

        //recalulcate max/min X/Y based on the new scale factor
        minX = ((self.getWidth() / mScaleFactor) - backGround.getWidth()) ;
        maxX = 0; //((self.getWidth() / mScaleFactor) + backGround.getWidth()) ;;//- (minX + backGround.getWidth());                   
        minY = ((self.getHeight() / mScaleFactor) - backGround.getHeight());
        maxY = 0; //((self.getHeight() / mScaleFactor) + backGround.getHeight());

        mScalePivotX = detector.getFocusX();
        mScalePivotY = detector.getFocusY();

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

private class DoubleTapListener extends  GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {     
                                Log.d(TAG,"TAP TAP");
                                        return false;                      
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return false;
        }
}
```

On Touch:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    //Check for pinch
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
            //check for double tap 
    doubleTapDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            ...
            }
     }
```